# How to delete the app list from My Apps?

Tags: apps, store

I am came from android. I am very new to Windows phone. I have download some apps from store. I don't like that apps and uninstalled that apps from my phone. Now when ever I go to My Apps list it showing all the uninstalled apps. I don't want to show that apps. I want to delete completely from My Apps List. Please help me to delete the My Apps List.

[image]

This is example screen shot.. I want to delete this apps..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the apps that you own, there is no mechanism to "un-own" them at present.

Comment: Rowland.. Thank you for the answer :-) ..  And Poor development by Microsoft. I hate that apps. And I don't want to use that apps. That's why I have uninstalled that apps. But When ever I go to my apps page it showing all the apps. Irritating..!! :-(

Comment: The fact remains that you've still purchased them, so you do still own them; I wouldn't really call it poor development to be able to reinstall an app that I'd uninstalled...

Comment: So.. If I installed 500 apps in my mobile. I uninstalled all that apps. So that the list will show that 500 app?? If I download another 500 app. That list will show 1000 apps? Is this good way to show the apps to the user??? Microsoft should add the feature to remove some apps from list.

Comment: @Vijay this behavior is similar to the Google App Store and Apple App Store

Comment: @MarcelJanus..  Ya.. But I can remove the app from the list in Goolgle Play store. I don't know about Apple..

Comment: AFAIK, Apple lets you "hide" purchased items (apps, movies...), but you can't completely remove them. I agree with Vijay, when you have tried a lot of apps, the "my apps" list becomes useless. And the thing is, it doesn't show the purchased apps only, but also the free ones.

Comment: @MichaëlPolla All apps are considered purchased at the price that was in force at the time (even if it were free) - app publishers can use this to offer a promotional price (say, free for the for first month after publishing) to drive downloads, before switching to charging later on. All the free downloading customers are still free to download the app later on, on additional devices.